# JQuery/HTML relationship in rebuilding twitter clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I'm building a twitter clone. I have been fiddling around with getting things to display for a while, and so far, no dice.

I see that the

```
 var $body = $('body');
 $body.html('');
```

clears out any html tags that could be written before the script loads (right?)

In the case of whats here, when I try to add html elements in the script itself, why is it still not visible? For example why doesn't the heading from

```
$upTop= $('<h1>Twittler</h1>').appendTo($body)
```

show up when I'm appending it to the body? I have looked around here and while there are similar questions, I have found no clear/definitive answers on something that will help me complete this.  I think I'll be good to go once I figure out how the relationship between how the 'div' and $body operate in the code. Please see code source below with comments.

Your help is already appeciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Twittler</title>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="data_generator.js"></script>
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="Twittler.css">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    var $upTop = $('<h1>Twittler</h1>').appendTo($body);
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.html('');

    var index = streams.home.length - 1;

    while(index >= 0) {
      var tweet = streams.home[index];
      var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
      $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
      $tweet.prependTo($body);
      index -= 1;
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>

<!--
Comments:
That file is called `data_generator.js`.  You don't need to understand the code that's in it, but here's what it does:

* Creates two global variables, `users` and `streams`.
  * `users` is an array of strings: all the usernames that you're following.
  * `streams` is an object with two properties, `users` and `home`.
    * `streams.home` is an array of all tweets from all the users you're following.
    * `streams.users` is an object with properties for each user.  `streams.users.albreyb` has all of `albreyb`'s tweets.
* Kicks off a periodic process that puts more data in `streams`.

You'll mostly be working in the javascript block of `index.html`. Note: The generated tweets will be displayed in reverse chronological order.


Basic Requirements:

- [ ] Show the user new tweets somehow.  (You can show them automatically as they're created, or create a button that displays new tweets.)
- [ ] Display the timestamps of when the tweets were created.
- [ ] Design your interface so that you want to look at and use the product you're making.
- [ ] Allow the user to click on a username to see that user's timeline.




We want to be able to have the new tweets show up (at the top of the page) when we click a button.
We want the old tweets to be maintained (in a different container/div?)
We want to be able to click the button again and shift those tweets down in to the container/div.. and so on.

-->
```

Comment: I'm not really sure about your question, because u are adding the Twitter h1 tag and then u clear body..

And the next think is: Why u using basic jQuery... i think the better way is AngularJS and the best way is Ruby on Rail.. Think about it

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what your question exactly is but as you said

```
var $body = $('body');
$body.html('');`
```

clears the body and

```
var $upTop = $('<h1>Twittler</h1>').appendTo($body);
```

adds to the body, but these things are running in opposite order. First you're adding to the body and then clearing it, so at the end it's empty.